# Visual Studio 2017 suggests to remove private field for public property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I just updated my VS2017 and it suggest me now to remove all private fields and just use public properties.

Original code:

```
private string description = "";
public string Description { get => description; set => description = value; }
```

Now it suggest I should just use:

```
        public string Description { get; set; } = "";
```

Am I missing something because I thought it was bad practice based on 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1051-do-not-declare-visible-instance-fields?view=vs-2017

What would be the correct way or what kind of advantage does one have doing it this or that way?

Comment: Properties are not fields. The new code is equivalent to the old code, except that the private field is now auto-generated by the compiler.

Comment: So I can stop to use the old version and just use the short version that is suggested?

Comment: The "Short" version is called **[Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)**.

Comment: And yes you can safely use them.

Comment: Yes, you can use the 'short version'. Btw, this has to do with upgrading to C# 3.0, not (directly) your Visual Studio version. If you are on it, consider upgrading to an even higher version, neet features are coming :)

Comment: @nilsK I already was on a higher version but I think the new update add this hints to the refactoring with additional out graying plus my unknowing about the Auto-Implemented Properties where leading to not care and just use the old way ;D

Comment: It makes properties that aren't currently doing anything "interesting" take up less space, giving more prominence in your code for the parts where you are doing something worth paying attention to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both implementations will generate the same underlying intermediate language code. However, the suggested changes will result in more human-readable code.

While the original code is not really difficult to read, it's more "wordy" therefore more effort for the next coder to read later (or yourself 6 months down the road). In order to understand the code with the backing field, you look at the get/set and then at the declared private variable to see what is actually being changed or used. The simplified code is all on one line and therefore requires less effort.

The warning in the [CA1051](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1051-do-not-declare-visible-instance-fields?view=vs-2017) document refers to having a public variable declared as opposed to a public property. The subtle difference is that the suggested syntax does implement the recommendation because the language allows a shortcut to not expose the underlying variable and still be easily read.